# Hidden div appears and MOVE as we hover on another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to have the Hidden div appears and MOVEs as we hover on another div.

My code works but it does not move as the moue moves on the div!And it makes sense because Im using hover! How can I solve this problem?

```
$('#questionMarkId').hide();


    $('a').hover(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#questionMarkId').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
        $('#questionMarkId').css( 'top', e.pageY );
        $('#questionMarkId').css( 'left', e.pageX );
        $('#questionMarkId').show();
    },function(){
      $('#questionMarkId').hide();

    })
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfi/m6XPP/107/)

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't move because, the hover is more like mouseenter and mouseleave.  So once the mouse is over an element, the event is not called.  Same would be when the mouse leaves

Comment: YEs I know this is the esence of hover! What can I use to do what I m looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery hover uses two events, mouseenter and mouseleave.

What you need is mousemove!

```
$('#questionMarkId').hide();

$('a').css("display", "inline-block").hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'position', 'absolute' );
    $('#questionMarkId').show();
},function(){
  $('#questionMarkId').hide();

}).on("mousemove", function(e) { 
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'top', e.pageY + 10 );
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'left', e.pageX + 10 );
});
```

[New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6XPP/109/)

PS: I've put the "display: inline-block", cause you need to use a block anchor, if not, the div will only show when you mouse move exactly over the letters, not all the block space.

Comment: Thats awesome! I just didnt understand why you used: .css("display", "inline-block")?

Comment: I've edited my post to explain it =)
Give a try without it in the fiddle and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m6XPP/110/)

```
$('#questionMarkId').hide();


$('a').hover(function(e){
    $('#questionMarkId').show();
},function(){
  $('#questionMarkId').hide();
}).mousemove(function(e){
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'position', 'relative' );
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'top', e.pageY );
    $('#questionMarkId').css( 'left', e.pageX );
});
```